# Randomizing Images in this jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

Is there a way to randomize the images in this jquery slideshow so it doesnt start with the same image every time the page refreshes?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">

<img src="http://image.jpg" alt="image 1" class="active">
<img src="http://image.jpg" alt="image 2" >
<img src="http://image.jpg" alt="image 3" >

</div>
```

And here is the script:

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 6000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');

    });
}

$(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 8000 );
});
```

THANKS!!!!

Comment: You can try `Math.random()` inside your slideswitch function. make it generate between 0 and 2 and use it to index your images

Comment: No because your images are hardcoded into your HTML. You could get javascript to switch it up upon loading the page (there would be a split second where image1 would always show) or you could make javascript put those image elements together and randomize which image takes on the `.active` class.

Answer (score 0):

you could randomly assign `active` class to your image tag on page load, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slideshow img").removeClass("active");
  randomDiv = $("#slideshow img").get().sort(function(){ 
     return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
  }).slice(0,1);
  $(randomDiv).addClass("active");
});
```

So that each time new img tag gets active class and will start from that img tag

Answer (score 0):

First define all images with class by number. Say, 'image 1','image 2', 'image 3' etc. Don't define active class to any image. Then use this code to randomly give any of the image 'active' class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
     $('.image ' + random).addClass('active');
})
```

If there are 'n' number of images, use var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * n);